MSP430FR6047 power supply- bypass capacitors
I'm working on MSP430FR6047 and I cam across a reference design from Texas instrument. In one of the supply pins they have use an 600 Ohm resistor as follows: Does any one know why? and what is the purpose of this resistor?


Pin in the MSP430FR6047:



Wouldn't that be a way to filter noise/isolate between two rails, VCC and a motor PVCC, using an inductor and capacitors?

It is not a resistor.
It is a ferrite bead.
It is used for filtering noise.

@ Justme, thanks, I just checked it and it is a Ferrite Bead, 600 ohm @ 100 MHz, 2 A, 0805
